# Miners selling bitcoins

Tags: transactions

I would like to know if Miners can sell their bitcoins only on the exchange markets and privately or they have other preferred channel to add them in the "market"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Their bitcoins are no different from any other. Most miners mine in pools where the pool operator initially gets the new bitcoins. Effectively the first thing he does is split them up among the (thousands of) pool participants. They do with them whatever they like.

Answer (score 1):

P2Pool and Eligius reward their miners with uncirculated coinage, which actually does have certain anonymity advantages...